# bytes with embedded literal \xhh escapes to unicode

Tags: python, unicode, escaping

I have: `b'{"street":"Grossk\\xc3\\xb6lnstra\\xc3\\x9fe"}'`

I need: `'{"street": "Grosskölnstraße"}'`

I tried:

```
s.decode('utf8'): # '{"street":"Grossk\\xc3\\xb6lnstra\\xc3\\x9fe"}'
s.decode('unicode_escape'): # '{"street":"GrosskÃ¶lnstraÃ\x9fe"}'
```

What's the correct way?

Comment: embedded UTF-8 bytes escaped, in what looks like a formath that *should* be JSON. How did you end up with this data in the first place?

Comment: I'm getting that from a HTTP request.

Comment: Do let the server administrators know they have a very broken JSON encoder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's.. quite a mess you have there. That looks like UTF-8 bytes embedded as Python byte escape sequences.

There is no codec that'll produce bytes as output again; you'll need to use the `unicode_escape` sequence then re-encode as Latin-1 to go back to UTF8 bytes, then decode as UTF-8:

```
s.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = b'{"street":"Grossk\\xc3\\xb6lnstra\\xc3\\x9fe"}'
>>> s.decode('unicode_escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'{"street":"Grosskölnstraße"}'
```

Another option is to target just the `\x[hexdigits]{3}` pattern in a regex; this may be the more robust option if the specific data wasn't produced by a faulty Python script:

```
import re
from functools import partial

escape = re.compile(rb'\\x([\da-f]{2})')
repair = partial(escape.sub, lambda m: bytes.fromhex(m.group(1).decode()))
```

`repair()` returns a `bytes` object:

```
>>> repair(s)
b'{"street":"Grossk\xc3\xb6lnstra\xc3\x9fe"}'
>>> repair(s).decode('utf8')
'{"street":"Grosskölnstraße"}'
```

Comment: Yay, it's working! Too bad I have no influence concerning the source of the data..